# Traduction de « Life is a roller coaster »

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Quelle est la tournure équivalente à *life is a roller coaster* ?

> life is a [roller coaster](https://bestonamusementparkrides.com/roller-coaster-rides-for-sale/): It means that in life, there are highs  and  lows. Sometimes it can be scary, sometimes it can be fun. The most important thing is to try and enjoy the ride. https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-meaning-of-life-is-a-roller-coaster

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/life+is+a+roller+coaster.html) donne :

> La vie est un véritable yo-yo. La vie est comme des montagnes russes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Une traduction utilisant une tournure idiomatique :

> Dans la vie, il y a des hauts et des bas.

Comment: Pour ce qui est des os de l'original c'est une traduction parfaite mais un squelette sans chair ne fait pas un corps ; qu'est-ce que vous faites de l'excitation dans l'ascension vers les hauts, de l'appréhension, du frisson en descendant des hauts, de la tenaille dans laquelle vous êtes quand l faut inexorablement soit monter soit descendre  en prise au vertige ? C'est n'est pas si dramatique pour tout le monde ? Vrai !

Answer (score 4):

En référence au [film d'Étienne Chatiliez](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_vie_est_un_long_fleuve_tranquille), on peut parfois rencontrer: *La vie n'est pas un long fleuve tranquille*.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une question de préférence, on ne peut pas dire qu'il y en ait une de mauvaise, mais on peut dire que l'une est meilleure que l'autre ; selon la façon acceptée de penser je préfèrerais « La vie c'est des montagnes russes. ». Selon mon point de vue personnel, je ne choisirais ni l'une ni l'autre mais je dirais d'abord en anglais « Life is a ride on a roller-coaster. » puis en français « La vie c'est un tour sur les montagnes russes. ».

Answer (score 1):

> La vie est [en dents de scie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_dents_de_scie).

- ‘En dents de scie’ est idiomatique du français
- Ça reste assez usité
- L'image de hauts et de bas est bien visible (mais moins spectaculaire que *roller-coaster*)

Comment: « En dents de scie » est en effet une expression idiomatique, mais on ne peut pas dire que ce soit idiomatique en combinaison avec « la vie ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est vrai, c'est corrigé. Du coup ce n'est pas tout à fait pertinent à l'OP, mais au moins cette expression aura été mentionnée.